# Django form is valid return that is NOT valid and error unknown

Tags: python, django

can anybody help me understand why the form is not validating?
I have the following error:
*>*

I don't get any error message unless I print the form.is_valid

The code is similar to what I normally use so it is strange that is not working this time.. I've looked the code over and over but can't find the issue.

Let me know if there is more code I should show
Thank you for any help you could provide.

## Views.py

```py
@login_required(login_url="sign-in")
def restaurant_add_meal(request):
    form = MealForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MealForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_meal = form.save(commit=False)
            new_meal.restaurant = request.user.restaurant
            new_meal.save()

            messages.success(request, "It's saved!")
            return redirect(restaurant_add_meal)

    return render(request, "restaurant/dashboard/add_meal.html", {"form": form},)</code>
```

And this is

## forms.py

```py
class MealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    meal_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        max_length=500,
        required=True,
    )
    short_description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        max_length=500,
        required=True,
    )
    image = forms.ImageField(
        widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control dropify"}),
        required=True,
    )
    price = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"class": "form-control price", "placeholder": "0.00"}
        ),
        required=True,
    )
    category = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"placeholder": "Ex. starters", "class": "form-control"}
        ),
        max_length=500,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        exclude = ("restaurant",)
```

Comment: What is your model? what do you get when you print `form.errors`?
calling form.is_valid won't throw any errors it's just return False/True value

Comment: I've solved it! thanks for your feedback. Printing the error I've noticed that I had the image field required and I wasn't call in it properly

Comment: I've posted that as a solution, please accept it to mark this as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `is_valid` won't throw any exception, you have to call `form.errors` and see what errors show up that need fixing